# how to save save a tpk file from export tile cache method in arcgis sdk for offline usage

Tags: android, arcgis-android-api

I am able to cache the tile from arcgis SDK and save it in a folder. But once I close the application and reopen it, I am not able to display the cached map in offline. can someone please help me how to save for offline usage..?

Answer (score 0):

Once the cache is saved in your device. It gets automatically displayed as it switches from online layer to local layer. Create a local tiled layer and add it to Map View in your onCreate method.

`ArcGISLocalTiledLayer arcGISLocalTiledLayer = new ArcGISLocalTiledLayer(defaultPath +File.separator+"Layers");
mMapView.addLayer(arcGISLocalTiledLayer);`